# C ++ code keeps bring errors. don't know what I did wrong?

Tags: c++

So I got homework for my class and have been sitting on this code for the whole day now. I don't know what I did wrong. I wrote down the algorithm and checked the code again, but I don't see anything wrong with it. Please help! The question and what I coded are in the code.

**code is anything below**

```
/*Write a program that calculates the average rainfall for three months. The program
should ask the user to enter the name of each month, such as June or July, and the
amount of rainfall (in inches) that fell each month. The program should display a mes-
sage similar to the following:

The average rainfall for June, July, and August is 6.72 inches.*/

/*
1. Declare variables for month 1, 2, and 3.
2. Declare variable for Total and Average Rainfall
3. Ask user to input name of months.
4. Then ask user to input inches of rain fall
5. Add all inches and then divide by number of inches asked. In this case, 3.
6. Display average inches of rain for all months to user.
*/
#include < iostream >
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string month1, month2, month3;
double month1Inch, month2Inch, month3Inch;
double averageInches;
double totalMonths;

cout << "Enter first month's name -";
cin >> month1Inch;
cout << "Enter first month inches -" <<month1<<;
cin >> month1Inch;

cout << "Enter second month's name - ";
cin >> month2;
cout << "Enter second month's inches -" << month2<< ;
cin >> month2Inch;

cout << "Enter third month's name -";
cin >> month3;
cout << "Enter third month's inches-" << month3 << ;
cin >> month3Inch;

totalMonths = (month1Inch + month2Inch + month3Inch);
averageInches = (totalMonths) / 3;

cout << "The average rainfall for" << month1 << "," << month2 << "," << "and" << month3 << "is" << averageInches << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
```

}

This is the first line of error message I get.

```
1>c:\users\prince\desktop\class work\tariqsalim chapter 3 number 4 .cpp(22): error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: i know what's wrong.  there's probably a bug in the code.

Comment: You'll have to tell us what's not working.

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this? You've dumped a load of code here with the words 'it doesn't work'.  You've given no description of what you're trying to do or what actually happens. You've listed no error messages, no sample input or output, nothing.

Comment: If you look at the comments, it asks the question I need a solution to. Also, the error code is too long to type in. I am using visualbasic 2013 to program this. It should calculate the average inches for all months after this. I literally don't know what I typed wrong! It is driving me crazy! Everything looks good to be able to calculate the average number of inches of all 3 inches of rain but I keep getting build errors.

Comment: Please post the specific errors you are getting. It is rather difficult to help you find a solution when you don't explain what the problem is.

Comment: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\ostream(699): or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<char,std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)'

Comment: That is the last line of error code I copied. Like I said, the whole thing is rather long and won't fit here.

Comment: You should probably put errors into the question instead of comments. Also you should usually look at the first error messages, not the last ones. The first are the ones that are the ultimate root, the last ones might only be some follow up mistakes of the compiler due to earlier errors.

Comment: 1>c:\users\prince\desktop\class work\tariqsalim chapter 3 number 4 .cpp(22): error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see multiple problems in your code, let me step through it:

```
int main()
{
    string month1, month2, month3;
    double month1Inch, month2Inch, month3Inch;
    double averageInches;
    double totalMonths;

    cout << "Enter first month's name -";
    cin >> month1Inch;  // you want to read the name into a double variable?
                        // you probably wanted month1 instead of month1inch here.
    cout << "Enter first month inches -" <<month1<<;    // month1 doesn't have a value yet, look above
            // also what is "<<;" supposed to do? you should probably get rid of the "<<" at the end.

    cin >> month1Inch;

    cout << "Enter second month's name - ";
    cin >> month2;
    cout << "Enter second month's inches -" << month2<< ;   // again get rid of the "<<" at the end.
    cin >> month2Inch;

    cout << "Enter third month's name -";
    cin >> month3;
    cout << "Enter third month's inches-" << month3 << ;    // see above...
    cin >> month3Inch;

    totalMonths = (month1Inch + month2Inch + month3Inch);
    averageInches = (totalMonths) / 3;

    cout << "The average rainfall for" << month1 << "," << month2 << "," << "and" << month3 << "is" << averageInches << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Also you should get used to compiler outputs, all except for attempting to read a string into a double variable are syntax errors that should give a clear error message.

Edit: Also just noticed we overlooked a very obvious problem. You need to `#include <string>`. Some compilers indirectly include parts of the `<string>` header through the `<iostream>` header which allowed you to define variables, but it still can't find the `operator>>` for strings.

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said but still not running. I put the first line of the error message above.

Comment: @user2221218 Added at the end, you're missing `#include <string>` which probably causes that problem. Try again with that fixed pls.

Comment: I did and keep getting build errors:    1>c:\users\prince\desktop\class work\tariqsalim chapter 3 number 4 .cpp(37): error C2065: 'totalMonths' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\prince\desktop\class work\tariqsalim chapter 3 number 4 .cpp(38): error C2065: 'totalMonths' : undeclared identifier

Comment: So I completely changed the name of "totalMonths" to "totalInches" for all parts and get this error message: 1>Tariqsalim Chapter 3 Number 4 .obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in Source.obj

Comment: ok, a linking error is something completely strange to get now since you only got a single source file. Try to deleting all the created .obj, .exe... files you got after compiling and recompile, maybe your compiler mixed something up. If that doesn't help you should probably do a new question with your new current code and all of the error messages since we're getting quite a bit away from the first errors you got.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `<<` from the end of all the `cout` statements, like

```
cout << "Enter first month inches -" <<month1<<;
```

should be

```
cout << "Enter first month inches -" <<month1;
```

Also,

```
#include < iostream >
```

should be

```
#include <iostream>
```

And there are other few errors that you should try to discover yourself using a debugger. See @AliciaBytes' more detailed response.

Comment: Actually, the whitespace in < > should not be a problem. Maybe my IDE just ignores it? What environment are you using?

Comment: I just quickly pasted the code in Sublime Text and compiled with g++4.9 under OS X.

Comment: I am using Microsoft VisualStudio 2013

Comment: I just double checked it on visual studio 2013. Whitespaces are not a problem on this IDE.

Comment: ok, possible, but still the other errors should be taken care of :) Both g++ and clang complain about white spaces in #include's

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. When the program started, I mistakenly had as source.cpp file and then made another file with the same code. So I just figured out that it is 1 source program to 1 project.